# How to assign values from form to Javascript session variables

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, session-variables

I am trying to create Javascript Session variables that will read information from one form and pass these variables to another form.

I can assign strings to these Session variables but i cannot assign values from Form elements to these variables

```
function SetUserName() 
{       
     <% var text1= "Charles";%>
     <%Session["UserName"] =text1;%>
     var session_value='<%=Session["UserName"]%>';
}
</script>
```

This is the Javascript on the first page which works and on a button click i call another page where i can display this Session Variable.

```
function LoadUserName()
{
    var username = '<%= Session["UserName"] %>';
    alert(username);
}
```

This gets called on load of second page. How can i pass values from HTML elements to the Session Variable?

For Example Say i have a Text Box

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="Address_Box" runat="server"  TextMode="MultiLine"
             MaxLength="200" ></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I send the text from this box to the session variable?

Comment: javascript directly can not "directly" set backend session variable.

Comment: JavaScript does not have sessions. ASP does.

Comment: Not knowing something doesn't get downvote - I corrected. He's here because he doesn't know

Comment: You can use cookies or HTML5 local storage for storing form values. But notice that such data are stored on client's machine which can be wiped away !

Comment: Thnks Xgreen, But is it not possible to assign a HTML element value to these variable instead of "Charles". Till now it works fine...

Comment: Maybe try to read something about client and server side programming. May start [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming) or on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
var session_value='<%=Session["UserName"]%>';
```

does not "access the ASP.Net session from javascript".

With this code you do generate (during the processing of the request) some text that will be sent to the browser. This text contains the string that results from the expression `Session["UserName"]`.

Once this text arrives at the browser it is interpreted as javascript. This javascript has no knowledge of any session values or the fact that it was (partly) generated.

You need to find some way to send data from the browser back to the server (using postback or ajax, for instance) before it can be stored in Session.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put this somewhere in your c# code.

```
Session["UserName"] = Address_Box.Text;
```

For a more complete answer I'd have to see more of your code. For a better solution you'd have to explain what you're trying to achieve