# how to add input value to session using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm getting the `question_id` from db and I'm showing it in the input field. I want store that input value also in the `$_SESSION`.

How do I do this?

My code:

```
<div class="questionfun" onclick="return ChatLoginMax(event, <?php echo $chat_question_id; ?>);">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">
    <p><?php echo $chat_question_title;?></p>
  </a>
</div>

<input type="text" id="chatquestionId" name="chatquestionName" value="">
    <?php 
        $_SESSION['session_name'] = $_GET['chat_question_id'];?>
```

Js:

```
function ChatLoginMax(event,chat_question_id){
   $("#chatquestionId").val(chat_question_id);
}
```

Comment: Any error in console ?

Comment: What `$abc = "<script>document.getElementByID('chatquestionId').value</script>";` should do ?

Comment: `$abc` will hold the specified string, not the value of the `input`.. It is basics...

Comment: k Tq can you tell me how to make that id in session

Comment: You have two options, either submit the form and handle form submission using `PHP` or use `AJAX`

Comment: Your title suggests you want to `echo` a value in PHP, your questions seems about how to add the value to the session. Confusing.

Comment: U can use like `onclick = "return ChatLoginMax(event,'<?php echo 
$chat_question_id; ?>');"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to assign values from form to Javascript session variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056472/how-to-assign-values-from-form-to-javascript-session-variables)